# Why does sshpass still prompt for a password?

Tags: ssh, password

The context :

- Debian Stretch workstation trying to SSH to numerous GNU/Linux servers (mostly RH and Debian)
- I can not change the SSH configuration of the remote servers
- I know this is far from ideal, but I have to login with login + password. No SSH key, plain old login/pass. I can NOT change this (no need to suggest using keys + passphrases)
- sshpass -V  : "sshpass 1.06"

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87956/can-you-set-passwords-in-ssh-config-to-allow-automatic-login#answer-634789) gives an interesting hint using 'ssphass'.

What I've set up in '~/.ssh/config' :

```
Host myServer
    HostName 12.34.56.78
    User bob
    ProxyCommand sshpass -v -pmyPassword ssh %r@%h -W localhost:%p
```

NB: the '-v' sshpass option is there only to get details while asking this question

When I try to connect via SSH :

```
me@myWorkstation$ ssh myServer
SSHPASS searching for password prompt using match "assword"
SSHPASS read: bob@12.34.56.78's password:
SSHPASS detected prompt. Sending password.
SSHPASS read:

bob@12.34.56.78's password:
```

And it waits like this forever :-(

If I edit '~/.ssh/config' and replace 'myPassword' (which is the real password attached to this SSH login, works when logging manually) :

```
Host myServer
    HostName 12.34.56.78
    User bob
    ProxyCommand sshpass -v -pnotMyPasswordAnymoreOhNo ssh %r@%h -W localhost:%p
```

which gives :

```
me@myWorkstation$ ssh myServer
SSHPASS searching for password prompt using match "assword"
SSHPASS read: bob@12.34.56.78's password:
SSHPASS detected prompt. Sending password.
SSHPASS read:

Permission denied, please try again.
SSHPASS read: bob@12.34.56.78's password:
SSHPASS detected prompt, again. Wrong password. Terminating.
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I actually get a reply (albeit negative).
Could you explain why ?

Answer (score 1):

man sshpass say:

> SECURITY CONSIDERATIONS
>
> ```
>   First and foremost, users of sshpass should realize that ssh's insistance on only  getting  the  password  interac‐
>    tively is not without reason. It is close to impossible to securely store the password, and users of sshpass should
>    consider whether ssh's public key authentication provides the same end-user experience, while involving less hassle
>    and being more secure.
>
>   The  -p  option  should  be  considered the least secure of all of sshpass's options.  All system users can see the
>    password in the command line with a simple "ps" command. Sshpass makes a minimal attempt to hide the password,  but
>    such  attempts  are  doomed  to  create  race conditions without actually solving the problem. Users of sshpass are
>    encouraged to use one of the other password passing techniques, which are all more secure.
>
>   In particular, people writing programs that are meant to communicate the password programatically are encouraged to
>    use an anonymous pipe and pass the pipe's reading end to sshpass using the -d option.
> ```

You can try save ENV variable and store pass there, but it's to bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

In case one is interested to force the `ssh` to ask password once, i.e. the time when `sshpass` provides a password and fail in case it is wrong, then something like this works nicely

```sh
sshpass -e ssh someuser@some.remote.server.com -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1 whoami
```

Explanation:

- `sshpass` takes the password from the `$SSHPASS` environment variable when using `-e` option
- `ssh` uses the password provided by `sshpass` and if successful then runs `whoami` command on the remote server
- if the password is wrong then it does not prompt for password because of the `-o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1` which forces `ssh` to only prompt once and that 1 time was already used by the wrong password provided by `sshpass`, hence the focus returns to the terminal

Comment: Even with this, the password is asked again on my part. I have no idea why, this is as if the `sshpass` part wasn't there. Any ideas what to do? Thanks